# How to write tests on clojurescript files pedestal?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, pedestal

I am trying to use TDD while learning pedestal, but I am stuck on how to write and execute tests (lein test) on .cljs files. I can't figure out where the tests would belong, and if it is possible to write theme in simple clojure or if I have to write them in clojureScript and run them in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/taylorSando/pedestal-todo/blob/master/test/todo/test/behavior.clj for examples of how to run tests against Pedestal apps, particularly the use of deftest in conjunction with clojure.test. I think most of your tests will be fine to be written in standard Clojure unless you are testing ClojureScript specific functionality.

[People](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pedestal-users/U2UhgNzEW3Y) have been using Midge to test their Pedestal apps.

A [similar problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pedestal-users/0eTiwgKUdfQ) was also discussed on the pedestal-users group.

Comment: I'm still restricted to testing only pure clojure fuctions with these, maybe i can just make the .cljs files .clj and use ^:shared
that seems to do what I need unless I start plugging into jQuery or something.